# Putting html through xml rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, xml

I'd like to update html data through an xml put request.
So what I've done is make an ajax request with the data

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "/network_internet_control_layouts/1.xml",
  data: '<network-internet-control-layout><layout>'+$("div#temp").html()+'</layout></network-internet-control-layout>',
  contentType: 'application/xml', 
  dataType: 'xml', 
  success: function(msg) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  }
});
```

When I look at my console, I see that the html code is escaped

```
Processing by NetworkInternetControlLayoutsController#update as XML
Parameters: {"network_internet_control_layout"=>{"layout"=>{"div"=>{"class"=>"tables", "div"=>{"style"=>"position: relative;", "class"=>"table", "div"=>{"class"=>"tablePart simple", "div"=>{"class"=>"block", "network_infrastructure_id"=>"1", "network_infrastructure_name"=>"VISI-201-NW"}}}}}}, "id"=>"1"}
```

And when it gets saved, it is totally wrong

```
AREL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `network_internet_control_layouts` SET `layout` = '--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess \ndiv: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess \n class: tables\n div: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess \n style: \"position: relative;\"\n class: table\n div: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess \n class: tablePart simple\n div: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess \n class: block\n network_infrastructure_id: \"1\"\n network_infrastructure_name: VISI-201-NW\n', `updated_at` = '2011-05-05 11:29:33' WHERE `network_internet_control_layouts`.`id` = 1
```

Is there a way to insert the raw data in the db?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568443/jquery-and-xml-with-cdata) where the [jquery is using CDATA for the HTML inside of XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568443/jquery-and-xml-with-cdata)

Try :

```
data: '<network-internet-control-layout><layout><![CDATA[' + $("div#temp").html() + ']]</layout></network-internet-control-layout>'
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, I did try out your code, but now I'm getting a 


    Declarations can only occur in the doctype declaration.
    Line: 3
    Position: 318
    Last 80 unconsumed characters:
    <![CDATA[       
    <div    class="tables"><div style="position: relative;" class="table
Line: 3
Position: 318
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
<![CDATA[       <div class="tables"><div style="position: relative;" class="table):

Comment: The solution was encrypting the html and decrypting it while getting it out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

From rails3, by default it html codes will not be embeded. How ever if you still want to embed html you have to use

raw

ex:

```
html_code = "<table><tr><td>This is a Sample</td></tr></table>

<%= raw html_code%>
```

will print a html table

HTH

sameera

Comment: Hi sameera,

The problem I think are the quotes that are used, if there is a class or id, the problems start. I already tried replacing them with other characters but this was no success.